# Creating Multiple Parametric Plots on the Same Graph

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I know how to create multiple parametric plots on the same graph via the following command:

```
    g[\[Zeta]_] := Sin[\[Zeta]];
    ParametricPlot[{{Re[g[\[Eta]*I]], 
       Im[g[\[Eta]*I]]}, {Re[g[.5 + \[Eta]*I]], 
       Im[g[.5 + \[Eta]*I]]}, {Re[g[1 + \[Eta]*I]], 
       Im[g[1 + \[Eta]*I]]}, {Re[g[1.5 + \[Eta]*I]], 
       Im[g[1.5 + \[Eta]*I]]}, {Re[g[2 + \[Eta]*I]], 
       Im[g[2 + \[Eta]*I]]}}, {\[Eta], -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}]
```

which produces the following image:
[image: output]
However, I also want to produce the exact same outputs only this time with the real part of the input negative (i.e. for $g[-.5 + \eta i]$) for every parametric plot already produced. Now I could easily do this by simply copy and pasting and then making a few changes. However, I am wondering if there is a more succinct way to do something like this. Can I for instance make some type of vector that contains all the discrete values for which I want the real part of my input to take to create a plot for? Or is my best option just copy and pasting?

Thanks for any help! I'm familiar and fairly good with Matlab, but I haven't used Mathematica much so trying to learn some of the tricks as I go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do this is to use `Map` (shorthand for `Map` is `/@`)and a pure function with `Slot` notation (the `#` you'll see a lot of if you use MMA for any amount of time):

```
g[\[Zeta]_] := Sin[\[Zeta]];
ks = Range[-2.5, 2.5, 0.5];
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{Re[g[# + \[Eta]*I]], Im[g[\[Eta]*I]]} & /@ ks]
 , {\[Eta], -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}
 , PlotRange -> {-3,3}
 ]
```

Obviously, you could have `ks = Range[0,2.5,0.5];` and do the same plot with `-ks` if you wanted two different plots. Just to show what you can do, you can also nest these expressions if you're careful about parenthesis:

```
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[
  {Re[g[#]], Im[g[Im[#]*I]]} & /@ (# + I*\[Eta] & /@ ks)
  ]
 , {\[Eta], -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}
 , PlotRange -> {-3,3}
 ]
```

Or make this a little easier to read, but still keep things in a limited scope using `Block`:

```
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[
  With[{gg = (# + I*\[Eta] & /@ ks)},
   {Re[g[#]], Im[g[Im[#]*I]]} & /@ gg
   ]
  ]
 , {\[Eta], -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}
 , PlotRange -> {-3,3}
 ]
```

You might want to check out [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) if you're new and looking to learn about MMA.

Answer (score 4):

```
p1 = ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate@
   Table[{Re[g[k + \[Eta]*I]], Im[g[\[Eta]*I]]}, {k, 0, 2.5, 0.5}]
  , {\[Eta], -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}
  , PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}
  , PlotLegends -> {"k = \[PlusMinus]" <> ToString[#] & /@ 
     Range[0, 2.5, 0.5]}
  ]

p2 = ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate@
   Table[{Re[g[k + \[Eta]*I]], Im[g[\[Eta]*I]]}, {k, 0, -2.5, -0.5}]
  , {\[Eta], -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}
  ]

Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

Note that I am plotting these separately and plotting the case for `k=0` twice to have symmetric colors on either side. The range can be adjusted to do all this using a single plot.